# Limit comment length

Tags: 8, comments

I'm trying to put a max number of characters that users can enter when they comment on an article, but what seems to be a simple task actually seems pretty hard to do. I found a module and several code snippets, but they are all for Drupal 7 and under. Ideally, they would also be a character countdown so that users know when they are about to reach the limit.

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D8 the fields of a comment can be configured in a comment type where you can define a field with a maximal number of characters. For a character countdown you need some javascript code or use a field module like [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength).